# "Could not find a JavaScript runtime". How do I install one?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, windows-10, execjs

I am unable to start a rails server. Apparently I don't have a JavaScript runtime.

```
$ rails s
c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
```

I went to the link

> https://github.com/rails/execjs

But I couldn't figure out what to do. So how exactly do I 'install' a JavaScript runtime?

Also here is my GemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 9):

> Could not find a JavaScript runtime

You need to install `nodejs`

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

or add `therubyracer` gem in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Comment: I've read somewhere that `therubyracer` does not work on Windows.

Comment: I don't know about it's not working on windows but yeah it's good to know

Comment: You can go with first option then in a **windows** way

Comment: But the thing is, I have nodejs but I'm still receiving the same error. What could be the reason?

Comment: Check for the `PATH` if you have

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that, please?

Answer (score 1):

Some gems requires a JavaScript engine (often just in development).

You could install NodeJS or [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) adding `gem 'therubyracer'` in your Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Install Node JS in your computer. get it from the [Node JS official Site](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: I did. I still receive the same error (I installed v6.9.2)
I'm running rails 5.0.1 and ruby 2.2.5