# ruby rails server not starting when i use command rails start in the correct directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im not enirly sure why but just to show that all the mail directory files are in there

```
$ ls
app     config.ru  Gemfile.lock  package.json  README.md  vendor
bin     db         lib           public        test
config  Gemfile    log           Rakefile      tmp
```

real problem is whenever I use

```
rails server
```

it pukes out garbage and the on thing I do understand of all of it is that 
uglifier had an error. anyone know a fix>
It could aslo be that runtime isnt installed but Im not entirely sure about that. It needs me to add details to this thats why my question is dragging on

```
rails aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the 
gem 'uglifier'.
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See 
https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/execjs-
2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/execjs-
2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/execjs-
2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/uglifier-
3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/uglifier-
3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in 
require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:78:in `each'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:78:in `block in require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:67:in `each'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:67:in `require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/hyperlisk/readit/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hyperlisk/readit/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/hyperlisk/readit/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-
12.2.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-
12.2.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-
12.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-
12.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-
12.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-
12.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `block in perform'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-
12.2.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `rescue in block (2 levels) 
in require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in 
require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:78:in `each'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:78:in `block in require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:67:in `each'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:67:in `require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/hyperlisk/readit/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hyperlisk/readit/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/hyperlisk/readit/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `block in perform'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See 
https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/execjs-
2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/execjs-
2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in 
`<module:ExecJS>'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/execjs-
2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in 
`<top (required)>'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/uglifier-
3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/uglifier-
3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in 
require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:78:in `each'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:78:in `block in require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:67:in `each'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:67:in `require'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-
1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/hyperlisk/readit/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hyperlisk/readit/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/hyperlisk/readit/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `block in perform'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/home/hyperlisk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-
5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

(OMFG SO MANY SPACES)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329995/could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime-how-do-i-install-one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails - Could not find a JavaScript runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have node.js installed on your system to fix the Javascript runtime error.

On OSX:

```
brew install nodejs
```

if your on Ubuntu  just run:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

and then run your server, rails s.

Answer (score 0):

If you read through your error message it says that you need to install a JavaScript Runtime.

If using debain/ubuntu you can `sudo apt-get install nodejs` to install Node

See: [Rails - Could not find a JavaScript runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)